# How to calculate the surface area of an object?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, surface-integrals

Calculate the area of the surface Y given by the equation $z = x^2 + y^2 − 1$ when $z ≤ 0$

Here is my solution:

[image]
I got the answer correct but there is something I just did (not toally randomly but I ignored certain requirements) which was the boundaries. In the question it says that $z\leq0$ but my boundaries where $0 \leq r \leq 1$ and $0 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi$ and I was wondering how in the hell my solution took into account that z is supposed to be less than 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You implicitly chose the boundaries of your parameterized integral in a way that satisfied the original condition. Indeed,

$$z\leq0\iff x^2 + y^2 \leq 1\iff r\leq 1.$$